# Spring Boot & Couchbase Stack Overflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase

Hi I have 2 simple classes in a bidirectional relationship which are causing infinite recursion resulting in an eventual stack overflow when serialising into JSON. I am using the `Spring Boot 2.2.2` starter project for `Couchbase` and Spring Web dependencies. My maven `pom.xml` file is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.stevie</groupId>
    <artifactId>stack-overflow-error</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>stack-overflow-error</name>
    <description>Reproduce Couchbase API Failure</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>13</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My domain classes are as follows:

Household.java

```
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document;

import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Field;
import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Document
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "@id")
public final  class Household {

    @Id
    private final String key;

    @Field
    private String type = "household";

    @Field
    private final String headSurname;

    @Field
    private final String headForename;

    @Field
    private final List<Member> members;

    public static Household of(String key, String headSurname, String headForename) {
        return new Household(key, headSurname, headForename);
    }

    Household(String key, String headSurname, String headForename) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.headSurname = headSurname;
        this.headForename = headForename;
        this.members = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getHeadSurname() {
        return headSurname;
    }

    public String getHeadForename() {
        return headForename;
    }

    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<Member> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Household [key=%s, headSurname=%s, headForename=%s]", key,
                headSurname, headForename);
    }

}
```

Member.java

```
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.Document;

import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Field;
import com.couchbase.client.java.repository.annotation.Id;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;

@Document
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "@id")
public final class Member {

    @Id
    private final String key;

    @Field
    private final String name;

    @Field
    private final Household household;


    public static Member of(String key, String name, Household household) {
        return new Member(key, name, household);
    }

    Member(String key, String name, Household household) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        this.household = household;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonBackReference
    public Household getHousehold() {
        return household;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Member [key=%s, name=%s]", key, name);
    }


}
```

My unit test (JUnit 5) is

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate;
import org.stevie.overflow.StackOverflowErrorApplication;
import org.stevie.overflow.domain.Household;
import org.stevie.overflow.domain.Member;

import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;

@SpringBootTest(classes = StackOverflowErrorApplication.class)
class HouseholdRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private HouseholdRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    private CouchbaseTemplate template;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    void throwsStackOverflowExceptionTest() {
        String key = manuallyGenerateKey("household");
        Household house = Household.of(key, "BLOGGS", "Joe");
        key = manuallyGenerateKey("member");
        Member m1 = Member.of(key, "Joe Bloggs", house);
        house.getMembers().add(m1);
        /** Following code throws Stack overflow exception!!!!! **/
        house = repo.save(house);
    }

    private String manuallyGenerateKey(String prefix) {
        Bucket bucket = template.getCouchbaseBucket();
        Long nextId = bucket.counter("counter::" + prefix, 1, 100).content();
        String key = prefix + "::" + nextId;
        return key;
    }

}
```

I want the JSON for the household to contain its member objects and the member to contain its household object. I have tried Jackson annotations such as `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonIdentityInfo` but Spring appears to ignore them. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do that, it's like sending a lot of data twice.... I suggest you  to use @JsonIgnore on your member object to not include household, and just iterate through the returned data on your client. Now if there are different flows in which you need e.g the household and it's members and in another one you need a member and it's household, I suggest you to create custom responses for those scenarios. Try to avoid over-fetching to much data.

Comment: Hi I have resolved this issue by fully normalising household which now has a list of member keys and member with has a single household key. I would still like to know why spring doesn't detect the JsonIgnore, JsonManagedReference, JsonIdentityInfo annotations.